# How do change implementation of a Jest mock for a certain test

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, jestjs

I've create a file in my `test/__mocks__` folder where I mock a npm module. And the link of this file is add to my jest setup. All work great this let me test it pretty nicely. But now for a certain test I need to change the return value from this one. How can I achieve this?

I try to unMock plus setMock etc. But nothing work.

```
// test/__mocks__/touchId.ts

jest.mock('react-native-touch-id', () => {
  return {
    isSupported: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
    authenticate: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
  };
});
```

And my test

```
it('should not navigate to main if touch id return false', async () => {
  jest.setMock('react-native-touch-id', {
    authenticate: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(false)),
  });
  const pinCreation = new PinCreationStore();

  const spy = jest.spyOn(NavigationServices, 'navigate');

  spy.mockReset();

  await pinCreation.verifyUser();

  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);

  spy.mockRestore();
});
```

Here I still get true so my test crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jest.mock()` without creating `__mocks__` folder.

For example:

`react-native-touch-id.ts`, I simulate this module in order to keep it simple. You can replace it with real npm module.

```js
const touchId = {
  isSupported() {
    return false;
  },
  authenticate() {
    return false;
  }
};
export default touchId;
```

`react-native-touch-id.spec.ts`:

```js
import touchId from './react-native-touch-id';

jest.mock('./react-native-touch-id', () => {
  return {
    isSupported: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
    authenticate: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true))
  };
});

describe('react-native-touch-id', () => {
  it('t1', () => {
    expect(touchId.isSupported()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(touchId.authenticate()).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('t2', () => {
    (touchId.isSupported as jest.MockedFunction<typeof touchId.isSupported>).mockReturnValueOnce(false);
    (touchId.authenticate as jest.MockedFunction<typeof touchId.authenticate>).mockReturnValueOnce(false);
    expect(touchId.isSupported()).toBeFalsy();
    expect(touchId.authenticate()).toBeFalsy();
  });

  it('t3', () => {
    (touchId.isSupported as jest.MockedFunction<typeof touchId.isSupported>).mockReturnValueOnce(true);
    (touchId.authenticate as jest.MockedFunction<typeof touchId.authenticate>).mockReturnValueOnce(false);
    expect(touchId.isSupported()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(touchId.authenticate()).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

As you can see, after you mock `react-native-touch-id` module, you need to import it and mocked again when you want these two methods to have different values. These mocked values will be used in other modules which import and use `isSupported` and `authenticate` methods of `react-native-touch-id` module.

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/52172531/react-native-touch-id.spec.ts
  react-native-touch-id
    ✓ t1 (5ms)
    ✓ t2 (1ms)
    ✓ t3

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.065s
```